# VS2013 :'Error while trying to run project:Unable to start debugging.'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

'Failed to process configuration file. Try to restart this appliacation.If failures continue try to repair your installation.'

Hi !
 So all the above is in the msgbox when I try to run any new project or existing sample in Visual Studio 2013 Community edition Update 4.
Thnx.

Comment: Native or dotnet or what project type you struggle with?

Comment: Have you tried the Repair process? "To repair Visual Studio, open Programs and Features (appwiz.cpl). From the Programs and Features window, right-click Visual Studio 2013 and select Change, and then click Repair to initiate the repair process."

Comment: So It finished repairing after 2-3 hours. And I have this message after repair is finished : "Setup Completed.However not all features installed correctly." Microsoft NuGet-Visual Studio 2013 Package failed.